# Python standards: What to type hint for returning multiple return types that share a base class

Tags: python, pep8

Quick question on type hinting a function that returns multiple inherited classes.

```
class Sub:
    pass

class A(Sub):
    pass

class B(Sub):
    pass

import typing

def func() -> typing.Union[A, B]:
    if cond1:
        return A
    if cond2:
        return B

#or should you do this?

def func() -> Sub:
    if cond1:
        return A
    if cond2:
        return B
```

Is it more appropriate to return the type hint for the subclass or should you use `typing.Union`

to return all of them.

Comment: I would use a Union, unless you know that the A & B are the only subclasses that there will be of Sub.  Also a Union is explicit.

Comment: I think that it's important to think about the consumer of your module/API.  Will the caller of `func()` be primarily interested in getting back a `Sub`, not so much caring about how it is implemented?  That is, will they be programming to the API defined by the `Sub` class?  If so, I'd use `Sub`.  If, on the other hand, the caller needs to clearly understand that they are only getting back an `A` or a `B` and never anything else, then the `Union` is a better choice.

Comment: It depends on how you expect the result of that method to be used. If the user should only call the methods they share, mark as `Sub`; if their specific methods are important, use the `Union`.

Answer (score 1):

[Mypy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/), a popular static type checker for Python, mentions the possibility of using a type variable with upper bound for a case similar to the one you mention:

- [The type of class objects](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects) describes how to use `Type` and a type variable with upper bound to annotate a function that receives a class and returns an instance of that class:

> ```python
> U = TypeVar('U', bound=User)
>
> def new_user(user_class: Type[U]) -> U:
>     # Same  implementation as before
> ```

The benefit of this approach seems to be that the checker will not reject calls to methods that are only present in a subclass, but not in the superclass:

> ```python
> def new_user(user_class: type) -> User:
>     # Same  implementation as before
>
> buyer = new_user(ProUser)
> buyer.pay()  # Rejected, not a method on User
> ```

- [Type variables with upper bounds](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#type-variables-with-upper-bounds) describes how to create and use a type variable with upper bound:

> A type variable can also be restricted to having values that are subtypes of a specific type. This type is called the upper bound of the type variable, and is specified with the `bound=...` keyword argument to `TypeVar`.

In your case you could use this:

```python
from typing import TypeVar

S = TypeVar("S", bound=Sub)

def func() -> S:
    # Your implementation
```